# How to parse time_t from string in C/C++ on Arduino-ESP8266?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm writing an embedded program on a ESP8266 Huzzah microcontroller programmed with Arduino, where i'm using it to make a weather station. I'm fetching some json weatherdata from a server where i can parse out the Date header on the request to know the current time (since the microcontroller dont have an internal clock), its in this format

```
Mon, 31 Aug 2020 18:11:26 GMT
```

I want the controller to update its forecast (blinking LED for rain), every day at 06:00, and get the next 12-24 hours forecast. The weather forecast JSON data gives the forecast with the format

```
2020-06-10T13:00:00Z
```

How do i parse these into `time_t` so i can compare them and calculate when to update my forecast?
I have looked in `time.h` in standard C library, but been unable to find a parser.

Comment: Try `strftime`..

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55248/how-to-parse-20180810t143000z-to-time-t/55271

Comment: I don't think Arduino is up to snuff, frankly not much is yet, but since you've tagged C++, I might as well turn you on to the glory that is [Modern C++'s time and date handling routines.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Comment: Are `struct tm`, and `strptime()` available in your environment?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `strptime()`, then consider this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
        struct tm tm = {0};
        const char *ts1 = "Mon, 31 Aug 2020 18:11:26 GMT";
        strptime(ts1, "%A, %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S GMT", &tm);
        printf("%s = %ld\n", ts1, timegm(&tm));
        const char *ts2 = "2020-06-10T13:00:00Z";
        strptime(ts2, "%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%SZ", &tm);
        printf("%s = %ld\n", ts2, timegm(&tm));
}
```

Comment: i don't have access to that function

Comment: @bogen I realise this is an old question, but to get access to `strptime`, you need to have `#include <time.h>`. Here's another example of how it works: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/83860/esp8266-iso-8601-string-to-tm-struct